# how to make css animation smoothly for full-screen page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, transition

This is my css

```
html , body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.screen-main{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    background-color:red;
}
.screen-login{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    background-color:green;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(100%,0%,0px);
}
.screen-login-left{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:green;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0%,0%,0px);
    -webkit-animation:right-to-left 0.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes right-to-left{
    0%{ -webkit-transform:translate3d(100%,0%,0px); -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;  }
    50%{ -webkit-transform:translate3d(50%,0%,0px); -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;  }
    100%{ -webkit-transform:translate3d(0%,0%,0px); }
}
```

My HTML ::

```
<body>
    <div class="screen-main" >main <a id="to-login-btn">to login</a></div>
    <div class="screen-login" >login</div>
</body>
```

my problem ::
it not smoothly transition!

how to fix them?
Some technique can help?
Can i use left or transform:translate() for transition ?
It about browser reflow ?(i don't sure)

please help me .  very thanks you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/12pw7e8y/ is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yesss ,  but i don't sure. it smoothly enough ?

Comment: i think it is fine , if you want more smooth juts increase the animation time.http://jsfiddle.net/12pw7e8y/1/

Comment: i don't sure about transition.
 it up to user GPU render ?

Comment: can you say what exactly is the problem?

Comment: thank for your help ( aktiv-coder )

Comment: we don't manually trigger the gpu .when we implement 3d animations the browser enables gpu rendering.if helped accept my answer :)

Comment: i think like you. we don't manually gpu.

Comment: yup check this https://www.urbaninsight.com/2013/01/04/improving-html5-app-performance-gpu-accelerated-css-transitions  hope it helps,

Comment: very helped thank again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for animation to happen you should add the animation class to any element

```
<body class="screen-login-left">
    <div class="screen-main">main <a id="to-login-btn">to login</a>
    </div>
    <div class="screen-login">login</div>
</body>
```

if you want it more smooth just increase the animation speed

```
.screen-login-left {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:green;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0%, 0%, 0px);
    -webkit-animation:right-to-left 3s;
}
```